# Add filtering to schemas created dynamically with hotchocolate (GraphQL)

Tags: .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm using the new interface (ITypeModule) introduced on the latest version of the hotchocolate framework (v12) to dynamically create all types of my schema. (https://chillicream.com/blog/2021/09/27/hot-chocolate-12#dynamic-schemas)

It's working well. But now I'm struggling to find out how to add filtering on my types using this stategy (since I can't use anotations and neither the descriptor like its done on the documentation (https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/fetching-data/filtering)

What I've tried so far:

My dependency injection:

```
// code omitted 
builder.Services
       .AddGraphQLServer()
       .AddTypeModule<DynamicTenantSchemaTypeModule>()
       .AddFiltering();
```

On the ITypeModule implementation (DynamicTenantSchemaTypeModule):

```
    //code omitted
    public async ValueTask<IReadOnlyCollection<ITypeSystemMember>> CreateTypesAsync(IDescriptorContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
            var types = new List<ITypeSystemMember>();
            var queryType = new ObjectTypeDefinition("Query");
            var schemas = await _documentSchemaRepository.GetSchemasAsync();
            foreach (var schema in schemas)
            {
                var schemaNamePascalCase = schema.Name!.ToPascalCase();
                var schemaNamePluralCamelCase = schema.PluralName!.ToCamelCase();
                var objectTypeDefinition = new ObjectTypeDefinition(schemaNamePascalCase);
                await AddFieldsAsync(types, schema, objectTypeDefinition, schema.Properties);
                queryType.Fields.Add(new ObjectFieldDefinition(schemaNamePluralCamelCase)
                {
                    Type = TypeReference.Parse($"[{schemaNamePascalCase}]"),
                    Resolver = async (ctx) =>
                    {
                        var documents = await _documentRepository.GetDocumentsAsync(schema.Id);
                        return documents;
                    }
                }
                .ToDescriptor(context)
                .UseFiltering()
                .ToDefinition());
                types.Add(ObjectType.CreateUnsafe(objectTypeDefinition));
            }
            types.Add(ObjectType.CreateUnsafe(queryType));
            return types;
}
//code omitted
```

But it throws the following exception:

```
HotChocolate.SchemaException: For more details look at the `Errors` property.

1. No default filter convention found. Call `AddFiltering()` on the schema builder.

   at HotChocolate.Data.FilterDescriptorContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GetFilterConvention>b__0()
   at HotChocolate.Types.Descriptors.DescriptorContext.GetConventionOrDefault[T](Func`1 defaultConvention, String scope)
   at HotChocolate.Data.FilterDescriptorContextExtensions.GetFilterConvention(IDescriptorContext context, String scope)
   at HotChocolate.Types.FilterObjectFieldDescriptorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<UseFiltering>b__1(IDescriptorContext c, ObjectFieldDefinition definition)
   at HotChocolate.Types.Descriptors.DescriptorBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<OnBeforeCreate>b__0(IDescriptorContext c, IDefinition d)
   at HotChocolate.Types.Descriptors.DescriptorBase`1.CreateDefinition()
   at HotChocolate.Types.Descriptors.DescriptorExtensions.ToDefinition[T](IDescriptor`1 descriptor)
```

Any ideas on how to add the filtering middleware correctly? Thanks!

Comment: I am dealing with the same problem. I believe you have to create your custom filtering convention (https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/api-reference/extending-filtering), for inspiration check the MongoDb filtering (https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/blob/ca0d44601a038dfd0895b375067f68d1dc911a19/src/HotChocolate/MongoDb/src/Data/Filters/Convention/Extensions/MongoDbFilterConventionDescriptorExtensions.cs).

Answer (score 1):

So far I got the filtering work on some field which I don't know where it comes from

1. apply filter convention in your code with configuration

```
descriptor.UseFiltering<MyFilterConvention>(f =>
{
  f.Name(schemaNamePascalCase + "OperationFilterInput");
});
```

2. create your custom filter convention `MyFilterConvention` by deriving from `HotChocolate.Data.Filters.FilterConvention` class
3. configure the convention to add a provider:

```
protected override void Configure(IFilterConventionDescriptor descriptor)
{
  descriptor.AddDefaults();
  descriptor.Provider(new QueryableFilterProvider(x => 
    x.AddDefaultFieldHandlers()));
}
```

This is the result for object `Foo`

```
foos (
    where: FooOperationFilterInput
): [Foo]

input FooOperationFilterInput {
  and: [FooOperationFilterInput!]
  or: [FooOperationFilterInput!]
  scope: StringOperationFilterInput
}

input StringOperationFilterInput {
  and: [StringOperationFilterInput!]
  or: [StringOperationFilterInput!]
  eq: String
  neq: String
  ... the rest is omitted for brevity ...
}
```